# GA4 purchase conversion events not reflecting in E-commerce purchases for app( Android/iOS)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics-4

We have a purchase conversion event that is triggered from an app (Android/iOS). I can see the event is reflected in the event section and conversion section in real-time, but after waiting for more than 48 hours I can not see these events in the E-commerce Purchase section and this has been the case since 22nd June.

We have checked the GA4 configuration, everything seems correct, and it was working fine till 21st June July.

We have observed this issue only for the Android and iOS mobile apps and not the web.

Let me know if any additional information is required.